# dxa-web-application-java issues while creating a new page

Tags: dxa

I am facing a couple of issues upon running the website provided in dxa-web-application-java.

1. We get 500 error when including assets/scripts/header.js, assets/scripts/main.js, assets/css/main.css in all the pages.

The links on the page are

```
<script src="/system/v0.82/assets/scripts/header.js"></script>
```

I don't have any folder v0.82 in my deployment.

2. Clicking on links pages aren't resolved. http://10.0.0.30:8080/about/contact. I have to append the .html to the link to get the page.
3. The index page of a link is not resolved so I end with pages with link http://10.0.0.30:8080/shindex  instead of http://10.0.0.30:8080/shindex/index.html

   root cause 
   java.lang.NullPointerException
       com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.markup.MarkupImpl.versionedContent(MarkupImpl.java:54)
       sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor229.invoke(Unknown Source)
       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:165)
       org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.invoke(JasperELResolver.java:147)
       org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
       org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:936)
       org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Views.Shared.ServerError_jsp._jspService(ServerError_jsp.java:106)
4. The about us and contact navigation menu on top right is shown as below
   http://http://10.0.0.30:8080/about/

We haven't mapped our ip to a domain name and so we are still using ip address in cd_dynamic_conf file like so

```
<Host Protocol="http" Domain="http://10.0.0.30" Port="8080" Path=""/>
```

Comment: Are you publishing everything correctly to the Broker database, or is your Deployer setup to store pages somewhere on disk perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1. Check the log files for more detailed information on your 500 error. You will not see a v0.82 folder on the file system as the design asset URLs are rewritten in the web application - this is just a cache busting method to ensure browser and other caches are invalidated when you publish new versions of the css/js etc.

For 2. & 3. The DXA works with extensionless URLs, so these links should just work without the .html extension and also without the index filename. Maybe the logs will provide some insight?

For 4. Remove the http:// from the Domain attribute in cd_dynamic_conf.xml and also check that this is not also the case in cd_link_conf.xml

Comment: I saw the below error in the logs for 1 `ERROR c.s.w.m.c.core.MainController - Exception while processing request for: /system/v0.3/assets/scripts/header.js
com.sdl.webapp.tridion.PublicationMappingNotFoundException: Publication mapping not found. Check if your cd_dynamic_conf.xml configuration file contains a publication mapping that matches this URL: http://10.0.0.30:8080/system/v0.3/assets/scripts/header.js`

Comment: For 4. when I removed the http:// from the conf file, the website as a whole does not load.I get from log                                                                                                           `15:40:32.038 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] ERROR c.s.w.m.c.core.MainController - Exception while processing request for: /shindex/index.html
com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.LocalizationResolverException: Exception while creating localization: [8] /
Caused by:com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.StaticContentNotFoundException: No binary variant found for: [8] /system/config/_all.json`

Comment: @Rache `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` really needs to be valid so in your case `<Host Protocol="http" Domain="10.0.0.30" Port="8080" Path=""/>` any typo's in there (like you had with adding the protocol to the domain attribute will break it for sure).