# DXA Java sending 500 status code for file not found

Tags: content-delivery, dxa, dxa-java, sdl-tridion

We are working on a website using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, Oracle 12c (CM & CD) and Java on the CD side. Any invalid URLs on the website (links that don't exist on the website) are generating 500 server error status code rather than sending a 404 file not found. Can someone kindly advice on how to fix this.

Comment: Check out http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12686/dxa-web-application-java-issues-while-creating-a-new-page - maybe this will help :-)

Comment: i faced similar issue in dxa.net in very earlier version, DXA try to guess the page if url ends with "/"  via suffixing index etc. if that guess url does not exist in broker. it throws 500.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I contacted SDL and was informed that this is a bug in the pre-release version of Java-DXA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Handles a {@code NotFoundException}.
 *
 * @param request The request.
 * @return The name of the view that renders the "not found" page.
 */


public String handleNotFoundException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
  String path = webRequestContext.getLocalization().getPath();
  String notFoundPageUrl = (path.endsWith("/") ? path : path + "/") + "error-404";

  Page pageModel;
  try {
      pageModel = contentProvider.getPageModel(notFoundPageUrl, webRequestContext.getLocalization());
  } catch (ContentProviderException e) {
      LOG.error("Could not find error page", e);
      throw new HTTPException(SC_NOT_FOUND);
  }

  if (!isIncludeRequest(request)) {
      request.setAttribute(PAGE_ID, pageModel.getId());
  }

  request.setAttribute(PAGE_MODEL, pageModel);
  request.setAttribute(LOCALIZATION, webRequestContext.getLocalization());
  request.setAttribute(MARKUP, markup);
  request.setAttribute(SCREEN_WIDTH, mediaHelper.getScreenWidth());

  response.setStatus(SC_NOT_FOUND);
  return this.viewResolver.resolveView(pageModel.getMvcData(), "Page", request);
```

}

The above code fixes the mentioned issues and correctly returns a 404 status code for file not found.